# Serious trouble with Bootstrap 3 footer, logo alignment is causing horizontal scrollbar to appear

Tags: html, css, twitter-bootstrap, twitter-bootstrap-3

[image: The footer as it should look]

The above picture is what my customer expects.  I'm using Bootstrap 3 to build it.  For the moment we do not have an "Our Team" or "Portfolio" page.  Whenever I try to get the picture to stay on the right side of the page, the row ends up being a little too wide for the page, and it  creates a horizontal scroll bar.

[image: The footer as it looks now, with problems]

I've made sure I'm nesting rows correctly, all of them are properly inside containers.  I've tried several approaches to the footer, The current thing I'm using is a bit of a workaround.  Here's the code for the footer:

```
#footer {
  height: 100px;
  width: 100%;
  position: absolute;
  left: 0;
  bottom: 0;
  background-color: @brand-secondary;
}
```

Here's the code for the secondary logo.  I think this is what's causing it to clash:

```
#secondary-logo {
  @picture-size: 150px;
  @rotation: -20deg;
  width: @picture-size;
  height: @picture-size;
    -ms-transform: rotate(@rotation); /* IE 9 */
  -webkit-transform: rotate(@rotation); /* Safari 3-8 */
  transform: rotate( @rotation );
  position: relative;
  top: -70px;
  right: -10px;
}
```

I've tried different combinations, right now the footer is a disaster.  I'm using the Bootstrap `nav` class to format the look and feel of the footer links, but when I don't use `nav` the `#secondary-logo` id will offset the logo in the desired way.  To put it simply, I'm looking for a specific solution to format this secondary logo correctly, and I'm willing to rework the rest of the footer layout to do it.  Here's the html:

```
<div class="container-fluid">
        <div class="row">
          <div id="footer">
          <div class="col-xs-12 text-center">
            <ul class="nav navbar-nav nav-bottom">
              <li><a id="home" href="#" onclick="return false">HOME</a></li>|
              <li><a id="services" href="#" onclick="return false">SERVICES</a></li>|
              <li><a id="contact" href="#" onclick="return false">CONTACT</a></li>
            </ul>
            <img id="secondary-logo" src="img/company_logoalt.png" class="img-responsive pull-right" alt="alternate logo">
            <span>© Company 2018</span>
          </div>
        </div>
      </div>
    </div>
```

Comment: please make a jsfidle, so it can be run and tested online.

Comment: @timpy did u solve the question ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

What changes I made:

1. Removed `<ul>` and replaced it with `<p>`, for less complication
2. Gave style of `display:inline` to above mentioned `<p>` to get them side by side
3. Fixed Bootstrap Grid problem, by adding new row to `<span>© Company 2018</span>`. It will give your Company 2018 to move to new line, that's what you are expecting
4. Fixed and small logo size, and changed `position:relative` to `position:absolute`

```css
#footer {
  height: 100px;
  width: 100%;
  position: absolute;
  left: 0;
  bottom: 0;
  background-color: lightgray;
}

#secondary-logo {
  @picture-size: 20px;
  @rotation: -20deg;
  width: 50px;
  height: @picture-size;
  -ms-transform: rotate(@rotation);
  /* IE 9 */
  -webkit-transform: rotate(@rotation);
  /* Safari 3-8 */
  transform: rotate( @rotation );
  position: absolute;
  top: -50px;
  right: 30px;
}
```

```html
<link href="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.7/css/bootstrap.min.css" rel="stylesheet" />
<div class="container-fluid">
  <div class="row">
    <div id="footer">
      <div class="col-xs-12 text-center" style="margin-top:20px">
        <p style="display:inline; margin:0px 20px;"><a id="home" href="#" onclick="return false">HOME</a></p>|
        <p style="display:inline; margin:0px 20px"><a id="services" href="#" onclick="return false">SERVICES</a></p>|
        <p style="display:inline; margin:0px 20px;"><a id="contact" href="#" onclick="return false">CONTACT</a></p>
        <img id="secondary-logo" src="https://encrypted-tbn0.gstatic.com/images?q=tbn:ANd9GcQeiBguO0475m-ltZwzjc0QAvOOcdmJ_2qmJ7D5VN0KfB4Hh6No" class="img-responsive " alt="alternate logo">
      </div>
      <div class="col-xs-12 text-center">
        <span>© Company 2018</span>
      </div>
    </div>
  </div>
</div>
</div>
```

Answer (score 0):

[I have make 1 example as u want where i have used cart image](https://i.stack.imgur.com/IQb1L.png)

```
#secondary-logo {
    top: -28px;
    right: 124px;
    position: absolute;
}
```

You need to add Position: absolute; for your logo image. using it Horizontal scrollbar will not come.